# Shared assembly in prism modules

Tags: c#, silverlight, prism, enterprise-library

I write a project using **Prism**.
I have tow modules and this modules have shared assembly.
for example a.dll refrenced by moduleA and ModuleB
therefore a.dll exists in ModuleA.xap and ModuleB.xap and enlarge xap files
and probably loades again for each module.

how i can solve this issue?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add this assembly to `Shell` project and set `Copy Local = False` to it in the modules. In this case assembly will be included just in `Shell.xap` file.